# requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent for Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, touch-event, android-scrollview, google-street-view

I have a StreetViewPanoramaView inside a linearlayout inside a scrollview:

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linear">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView
                android:id="@+id/street_view_panorama"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <other views - textviews etc>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

The StreetViewPanoramaView allows a user to move the streetview camera up and down and left and right. I want the scrollview to stop intercepting the user touch events when the user is moving the camera. Currently, if the user moves the camera in the StreetViewPanoramaView, the scrollview intercept the touch and moves the scrollview instead.

I tried this code from https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/prevent-touch-event-theft-in-android/ but its doesn't seem to be working (scrollview is still taking the touch events):

```
      mStreetViewPanoramaView = (StreetViewPanoramaView) findViewById(R.id.street_view_panorama);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams streetViewLp =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, displaymetrics.widthPixels/3);
        mStreetViewPanoramaView.setLayoutParams(streetViewLp);

        disableTouchTheft(mStreetViewPanoramaView);

public static void disableTouchTheft(View view) {
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            view.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

Things I have tried:

I have made a custom view and imported the code dispatchTouchEvent into my activity code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int[] loc = {0, 0};
        mStreetViewPanoramaView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);

        Rect rect = new Rect(loc[0], loc[1] , loc[0] + mStreetViewPanoramaView.getWidth(), loc[1] + mStreetViewPanoramaView.getHeight());


        if (rect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
            Log.e("stretview", "dispatched");
            return mStreetViewPanoramaView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
/*            return true;*/

        }else{
            //Continue with touch event
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }

public class CustomStreetViewPanoramaView extends StreetViewPanoramaView {

    public CustomStreetViewPanoramaView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomStreetViewPanoramaView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomStreetViewPanoramaView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomStreetViewPanoramaView(Context context, StreetViewPanoramaOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false; // Do not intercept touch event, let the child handle it
    }
}
```

The code appears to half-work - it appears that the StreetViewParnoramaView will obtain the touch events for the top half of the view but the bottom half does not obtain any touch events.

My full layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout">

            <com.example.simon.customshapes.CustomStreetViewPanoramaView
                android:id="@+id/street_view_panorama"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:id="@+id/card"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello card"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save panorama"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/savepano"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of Johann is the right path but still not working - this one will work

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (streetView != null) {
        streetView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

        if (rect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
            event.offsetLocation(-rect.left, -rect.top);
            streetView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return true;

        } else {
            //Continue with touch event
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    } else {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

dispatchTouchEvent of the activity and move the event after offsets it to the streetView

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. For anyone who is looking to do something similar, this is the correct code and you must put this code within your activity class.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following...

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int[] loc = {0, 0};
    mStreetViewPanoramaView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);

    Rect rect = new Rect(loc[0], loc[1] , loc[0] + mStreetViewPanoramaView.getWidth(), loc[1] + mStreetViewPanoramaView.getHeight());


    if (rect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {            
        mStreetViewPanoramaView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return true;

    }else{
        //Continue with touch event
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This hopefully will check if the touch was on the panoramaview and handle accordingly.

Comment: I assume you mean create a custom StreetViewPanoramaView class and then override dispatchTouchEvent. I tried your method but was unsuccessful as the code here: mStreetViewPanoramaView.dispatchTouchEvent(event); is a circular reference and causes a stackoverflow error. If I take out the line, the code runs but the view cannot scroll at all.

Comment: I meant trying to override the activity's dispatch touch event...or else create custom class for your main container layout and override that one..the override must be on top of both scrollview and panorama view

Comment: I tried your code by pasting it within my activity class and i can see that the condition (rect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY()))  is met and it is calling the mStreetViewPanoramaView.dispatchTouchEvent(event); when i try to move left, right, top, down on the streetview, but the streetview does not move at all.

Comment: if you touch outside the scrollview moves?

Comment: Yes. It moves, I have a cardview and a recyclerview inside the scrollview and if I fling either of them, they move the scrollview

Comment: so strange...and this is the only solution i can think of.

Comment: I haven't tried this but maybe I should just return Mstreetviewpanoramaview.dispatchTouchevent(event) instead of returning true afterwards. Return true means the activity would have consumed the event and we dont want the activity to consume it. Will try that tomorrow.

Comment: I think the reason why it is not working 100% is the formula mStreetViewPanoramaView.getLocationOnScreen. Its sortof half-working with events being given to the streetviewpanoramaView and I think it is not calculating the location of the view correctly which is why not all touch events are propagated to the view. Can you please have a look at the updated question layout xml and see if you can spot what formula would work appropriately with it to calculate the correct rect?

Comment: can you try getY() and getX() ...try to logcat both (getY and locationonscreen)...and see if the numbers are making sense depending on your device....if the Y is the Y in the scrollview you may calculate scollops